# how to get the right result from mongodb in php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

i have a object like this:

```
$testData = array(
     'name' => 'joyCood',
     'nick' => 'hello',

     'friends' => array(
        array('friend_id' => 98, 'readable' => 8),
        array('friend_id' => 97, 'readable' => 0),
        array('friend_id' => 96, 'readable' => 0)
     ) 
);
```

my query sql is:

```
$macher = array('friends.friend_id' => 98, 'friends.readable' => 0);
$mongo->find($macher);
```

the result is:

```
$testData = array(
     'name' => 'joyCood',
     'nick' => 'hello',

     'friends' => array(
        array('friend_id' => 98, 'readable' => 8),
        array('friend_id' => 97, 'readable' => 0),
        array('friend_id' => 96, 'readable' => 0)
     ) 
);
```

the problem is: the readable is not eq 0, why the mongodb return this object to me? the right result will be return nothing will be fine. help me please!

Comment: "readable" is `0` in several of the elements in the array for the document, so yes this is a match. Are you in fact asking where "none" of the array content has a "readable" `0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this now. The problem here is that that conditions as you have listed them are considered across **all** array members and not just an individual one. To do this you need [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

```
$macher = array( 'friends' => array( '$elemMatch' => array( 
    'friend_id' => 98, 'readable' => 0
)));
```

This considers each element to have the "same" query conditions. Otherwise there are actually elements "somewhere" in the array that match each condition and the match is `true`.

Basically a "little query" that is applied to each element of the array to see if both conditions are true.